# Regex: Optional text inside parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, anki

Here's my code. It's used for customizing the typing box in anki:

```js
function main() {
//Script for modifying 'Show Answer' behavior for Input types.
var htmlTextNodes = [];
var innerHTMLText = [];
if (!document.getElementById('typeans')) {
  return;
}
var htmlNodeLength =document.getElementById('typeans').childNodes.length;
var typedAnswer;
var correctAnswer;
var firstBr = null;
var secondBr;

//capture each node to array
for (i = 0; i < htmlNodeLength; i++) {
 
 htmlTextNodes[i] = document.getElementById('typeans').childNodes[i];
 innerHTMLText[i] = document.getElementById('typeans').childNodes[i].innerHTML;
 //locate <br> tags for output change markers
 if (document.getElementById('typeans').childNodes[i].nodeName == "BR") {
  console.log("Runs if BR");
  if (firstBr != null) {
   secondBr = i;
  } else {
   firstBr = i;
  };
 };
};

//If answer is correct, firstBr will still be null, so must set to length of typeans.childNode
if (firstBr == null) {
 firstBr = htmlNodeLength;
};

//assemble typed and correct answer strings
str2 = innerHTMLText.slice(0,firstBr).join("");
var typeParse = str2.replace(/[^\w,éôëçñï]/g,' ');
var typedAnswer = typeParse.replace(/\s/g, '');
var typedAnsDis = str2.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9,éôëçñï]/g,' ');
var typedUpper = typedAnswer.toUpperCase();

//typedUpper = "KITTEN"

var corr = document.getElementById('correctAnswer');
var str2 = corr.innerHTML;
var correctParse = str2.replace(/[^\w,éôëçñï]/g,'');
var correctAnswer = correctParse.replace(/\s/g, '');

//split alternative answers into array

var getalt = document.getElementById('altmean');
var altmean = getalt.innerHTML.replace(/(\([^)]*\))/g, '').replace(/[^\w,éôëçñï]/g,' ');

altmean += ", ";
altmean += correctAnswer;

var array = altmean.split(",").map(function(item) {
  return item.trim();
});
if (!array.includes(correctAnswer)) {
  array.push(correctAnswer);} 

for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    array[i] = "" + array[i].toUpperCase() + "";
    array[i] = "" + array[i].replace(/[/\W, " "]/g,' ');; + "";
    array[i] = "" + array[i].replace(/\s/g, ''); + "";
}

//Modify answer output
if ((array.indexOf(typedUpper) > -1) &&  (!(typedUpper == "" ))) {
 var c = "<div class=\"animated zoomIn\" id='correct'>"+typedAnsDis+"</div>";
 var d = document.getElementById('typeans');
 d.innerHTML =  c;
} else {
if(typedAnsDis == "") {
 var g = "<div class=\"animated shake\" id='empty'>{{Meaning}}"+typedAnsDis+"</div>";
 var h = document.getElementById('typeans'); 
 h.innerHTML =  g;
const div = document.getElementById('empty');
div.innerHTML = div.textContent.split('').filter(char => /^[A-Za-z\s\.,;!?"'-～-éū]+$/.test(char) && !/[^\x00-\x7F]/.test(char)).join('');
} else {
 var e = "<div class=\"animated  flash\" id='incorrect'>"+typedAnsDis+"</div>";
 var f = document.getElementById('typeans');
f.innerHTML =  e;
}
}
};
main();
```

Let's say I have a text like "(text1) text2". I want to find a way to make the script consider both "text1 text2" and just "text2" as correct answers.

Till now I found out

```js
var correctParse = str2.replace(/(\([^)]*\))/g, '').replace(/[^\w,éôëçñï]/g,'');
```

considers only "text2" as a correct answer while

```js
var correctParse = str2.replace(/(\([^)]*\))/g, '$1').replace(/[^\w,éôëçñï]/g,'$1');
```

considers only "text1 text2" as a correct answer. I can't find a way to count both "text1 text2" and "text2" correct depending on what I type.

Comment: As the question seems to only relate to the value of `str2`, please provide examples of `str2` and the corresponding values you expect for `correctParse`. It doesn't seem that your HTML related code has anything to do with your question. If it does, please clarify.

Comment: Could you explain what is `.replace(/[^\w,éôëçñï]/g,'')` for? It looks like you are trying to remove non-letters, but what about "Elève" (student in french). Isn't `è` allowed? I would use this instead, to remove all non-letter chars: `.replace(/\P{L}/gu, '')`. `\p{L}` matches any letter in any language, and `\P{L}` matches any not-letter. This only works if you activate the `u` flag for **u**nicode. You can also allow ponctuation. See details here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category

Comment: @trincot the value of str2 is the correct answer (ie the the text inside the meaning field in my anki deck). So for example a have a word like テーブル席 which has the meaning of (seat at a) table. And I want to find a way for the script to consider both "seat at a table" and just "table" as correct answers.

Comment: @PatrickJanser ,éôëçñï mentions any accented character that might be used inside the meaning field. The meaning is usually in English so not many accented characters appear.

Answer (score 1):

try to match the entire input /^...$/ with an optional capturing group (?:...)? for text1 that might or might not appear in the input...

```
str2.replace(/^((?:\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\)\s+)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+).*$/, $1)
```

see https://regex101.com/r/CulGff/1

Comment: I actually managed to find a solution to my problem
Instead of trying to change str2 I made it so text inside the parentheses counts as an alternative answer

altmean += "/[) (, ]/"
altmean += correctAnswer;

`var array = altmean.split(/[(),]/).map(function(item) {
  return item.trim();
});

if (!array.includes(correctAnswer)) {
  array.push(correctAnswer);
}

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = "" + array[i].toUpperCase() + "";
  array[i] = "" + array[i].replace(/[/\W(), " "]/g,' '); + "";
  array[i] = "" + array[i].replace(/\s/g, ''); + "";
}`